# How to parse the output from the web service which gives out JSON as output format. And I am using REST

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wsdl

How do I parse the output i.e., `responseText`?

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    //read response
    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    return responseText;
}
```

And, I know that **string** is the return type which I have specified as mentioned below.

```
public string InvokeRequest(RESTInvokeClass objInvoke)
```

I think the complete output(some 100 lines) which is in the JSON format is completely displaying as a single string stopping me to parse the output.

My question is:
How to receive the output so that I can parse through it?

Comment: *which is in the JSON format is completely displaying as a single string stopping me to parse the output.* How is it stopping you from parsing it?

Comment: What your asking is not clear. If you just want to parse the Json doc that has been retrieved, you can use DataContractJsonSerializer, JSon.net...

Comment: Ok, How do i receive the output?  As of now i am receiving the output as responseText which is of type string. Is it the correct way to receive the OUTPUT from the webservice (Output:which contains some user details in JSON format) before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to serialize the reponse text to an object that you can traverse through, you can do something like:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var riClass = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(responseText);

foreach(var item in riClass)
{
    //Do something with this item
}
```